# How do you get Mathematica to start a task in the background?

Tags: windows, version-6, run

Mathematica-6, Windows-10.

How do you get Mathematica to start a task in the background? Function

```
Run["START \"xxx\" /D " <> dirname <> " /MIN /B /WAIT xxx.EXE"];
```

does not work in spite of the /MIN option. Option /B starts the task without creating a cmd.exe window but the task starts in the foregound. On the other hand,

```
Run["START \"xxx\" /D " <> dirname <> " /MIN /WAIT xxx.EXE"];
```

does start the task in the background but it creates a blank cmd.exe window in the foreground.

What I want is the task to start without one or two windows popping into existence on top of whatever I happen to be doing at the time.

Comment: You might have a hard time finding people with Mathematica 6 to test this on :)

Comment: Perhaps the Mathematica version is not relevant. Can anyone with any recent version of Mathematica advise what to do, please?

Comment: Come on, guys! Wake up! Someone, somewhere must know how to resolve this problem one way or the other. It is driving me round the bend!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is the Mathematica internal function [StartProcess](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html).

Here is a usage example:

```
pthExe=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"run.exe"}];
arguments={1,2,3};
process=StartProcess[Join[{pthExe},arguments]];
While[ProcessStatus[process] == "Running", Pause[0.1];];
```

Since I assume you want to work on the output of your external program, I added code to repeatedly pause mathematica's execution until the external program is finished.

This works in Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 11. I am not sure your problem has a solution without `StartProcess[]`.